# SQL Agent Job - No Access to share

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I've got a SQL agent job, the first step is of type: Operating System (CmdExec), it's running as a Proxy which I created.

The command: `\\ShareDrive\Program.exe`

I have given the user of my Proxy rights on the `ShareDrive` folder share, but when I start the job I am always getting the following error:

> Executed as user: ProxyUser. The process could not be created for step
>   1 of job 0xDA12CDA08820804EB95F551C1B2936E0 (reason: Access is
>   denied).  The step failed.

I have tried setting the folder security to allow EVERYONE access, in this instance the job runs fine with no access issues, but poses a security risk.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a share, there are two levels of security:

1. for the physical folder
2. for the share

The most restrictive permissions of the two is in effect.

Make sure that the windows account of the ProxyUser has proper permissions on both levels.